# Populate an array with certain values at certain positions in snowflake

Tags: arrays, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Let's say that I have this table:

| Key | Index | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 | 10 |
| 1 | 5 | 18 |
| 1 | 14 | 4 |
| 2 | 2 | 11 |
| 2 | 13 | 24 |
| 2 | 29 | 40 |

I want to construct an array in Snowflake where the dimension of the array is always 50, the default value is zero, and I wanna populate the array with certain values at certain positions according to Index and Value columns. The desired output is

| Key | Array |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | [0,0,0,10,0,18,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,4,0,...,0] |
| 2 | [0,0,11,0,...,0,24,0,...,0,40,0,...,0] |

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**UPDATED TO USE A SET BASED APPRAOCH**

Instead of using string manipulations and aggregations, this can be done in a much simpler way using a set based approach. I don't know why it didn't occur to me sooner.

```
with cte as

(select key,
        row_number() over (partition by key order by 1)-1 as index, 
        0 as value
 from table(generator(rowcount=>50)) cross join (select distinct key from t)

 union
 select key,index,value 
 from t

 minus
 select key,index,0
 from t)

select key,array_agg(value) within group (order by index) as value_array
from cte
group by key
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this.

```
with my_data as (
    -- data table as cte
    select
        1 as Key,
        3 as Index,
        10 as Value
    union all
    select
        1,
        5,
        18
    union all
    select
        1,
        14,
        4
    union all
    select
        2,
        2,
        11
    union all
    select
        2,
        13,
        24
    union all
    select
        2,
        29,
        40
),
index_cte as (
    -- generate 1-50 index values
    select
        row_number() over (
            order by
                seq4()
        ) as fixed_index
    from
        table(generator(rowcount => 50))
),
keys_fixed_index as(
    -- cross join distinct keys with fixed_index values
    select
        distinct key,
        fixed_index
    from
        my_data
        cross join index_cte
)
select
    distinct
    t1.key,
    ARRAY_AGG(ifnull(value, 0)) WITHIN GROUP (
        order by
            t1.fixed_index asc
    ) OVER (PARTITION BY t1.key) as array
from
    keys_fixed_index t1
    left join my_data t2 on t1.key = t2.key
    and t1.fixed_index = t2.index
order by
    key
```

| KEY | ARRAY |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | [ 0, 0, 10, 0, 18, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ] |
| 2 | [ 0, 11, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 24, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 40, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ] |

Comment: I think that when generating the index table "index_cte", you should simply have: "seq8() as fixed_index" because the indices start from 0.

Comment: SEQ1 / SEQ2 / SEQ4 / SEQ8 are all zero-indexed, and not guaranteed to be gap-free.
The only way to guarantee a gap-free sequence is with row_number() 
https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/seq1.html